# Making my windows 10 IIS server as a hosting server, test purpose

Tags: iis, networking

I have a REAL IP. XXX.XXX.XX.XXX, with that, i have DNS, Subnetmask, gateway and secondary dns from my ISP provider.

I have connected my PC (windows 10) with that setting in TCP/IP v4. And network is fine for outgoing.

Now I build a simple html web site and created a site in IIS 10. in Binding, I used the REAL IP, with port 80. From that pc, after hitting the IP Address, I am getting into the site. But from outside the network, via internet, If I hit the IP, nothing comes except `Problem loading page` with respond timeout.

How can I access the IP from outside internet?

Comment: You're sure it's a publicly reachable IP address? Maybe you have a firewall running on the PC?

Comment: Did you check if your site is running on a port that may be blocked by your windows firewall? Most likely you will need to create an inbound firewall rule to make your IIS on Windows 10 accessible from outside.

Comment: I am not certain about the firewalls. How to check and what to chek? Can you please give a direction please

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have followed this link : http://superuser.com/questions/144482/windows-firewall-how-to-allow-traffic-on-a-specific-port-eg-8080

And created a new role for port 80. But I yet not got any result

Comment: Are you sure it's really a publicly accessible IP? It's not a local one?

Comment: Yes. That was a real IP, but anyhow not allowed to access from outside by the ISP provider. Thanks all.